# How do I implement the repository to my project using MVVM with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I just want so bad to learn MVVM. It's kinda hard for me, so I've decided to ask here for help. I've make some dummy "project" to receive data from server through the retrofit. For now, everything seems to work properly, but I've noticed that the example that I was following doesn't have repository in it, and I'm not sure how should I implement that, could I have some help over here, please?

Here's the code from whole project

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
PostsAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
PostsViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostsViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getPosts();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new PostsAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewModel.postsMutable.observe(this, new Observer<List<Posts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Posts> list) {
            adapter.setPostsList(list);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Posts> postsList = new ArrayList<>();


public void setPostsList(List<Posts> postsList){
    this.postsList = postsList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Posts posts = postsList.get(position);

    if (postsList == null) return;

    holder.textView.setText(posts.getText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postsList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
 }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class PostsViewModel extends ViewModel {

MutableLiveData<List<Posts>> postsMutable = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void getPosts(){
    RetrofitBuilder.getInstance().getPosts().enqueue(new Callback<List<Posts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Posts>> call, Response<List<Posts>> response) {
            postsMutable.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Posts>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
 }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Posts {

@SerializedName("userId")
private int userId;

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("body")
private String text;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
 }
}
```

**Retrofit Builder**

```
public class RetrofitBuilder {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
private ApiCalls api;
private static RetrofitBuilder instance;


public RetrofitBuilder() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    api = retrofit.create(ApiCalls.class);
}

public static RetrofitBuilder getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RetrofitBuilder();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Call<List<Posts>> getPosts(){
    return api.getPosts();
 }
}
```

**Api calls**

```
public interface ApiCalls {
@GET("posts")
Call<List<Posts>> getPosts();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Repository` is just where you get all your data from whether it be http calls or database so all you have to do is create a class and put your retrofit calls in there instead of the view model.

So your `getPosts()` would look something like this

```
public void getPosts(){
    List<Posts> posts = myRepository.getPosts();
    postsMutable.setValue(posts);
}
```

adjust to your needs but thats roughly what you will be doing. I believe retrofit even supports livedata now so it might be even easier than that